# Conditional REPLACE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The table project contains

```
projectid|description|statuscode|path|....
```

I have a SQL clause which should return the following (pseudocode):

```
SELECT ...,  
     CASE   
     WHEN statusCode IN ('C', 'N', 'F') 
       IF (path contains 'CLOSED PROJECTS')
       THEN   
        REPLACE(path,'CLOSED PROJECTS','DEAD PROJECTS') 
       ELSE
        REPLACE(path,'ACTIVE PROJECTS','DEAD PROJECTS') 
,
.....
from Project where projectId=.....
```

How do I implement this 'conditional' `REPLACE`?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be like this..

```
SELECT ...,  
 CASE   
 WHEN statusCode IN ('C', 'N', 'F') 
   and path like '%CLOSED PROJECTS%'
   THEN   
    REPLACE(path,'CLOSED PROJECTS','DEAD PROJECTS') 
   ELSE
    REPLACE(path,'ACTIVE PROJECTS','DEAD PROJECTS') 
,
.....
from Project where projectId=.....
```

Comment: I think the `contains` predicate can only be used in the `WHERE` clause, so only the latter solution works.

Comment: @NickyvV - Yes you are right. Removed it from the answer

Comment: Just to make sure, this can be understood in two ways. One: You want to replace CLOSED projects on rows where statusCode is C/N/F, and replace ACTIVE projects on all other rows regardless of statusCode (which is what the answer above does). Two: You you only want to do ANY kind of replacing on rows where statusCode is C/N/F, but what you replace path with, depends on whether it contains CLOSED or not. There is a difference. :)

Comment: @Kahn I agree with you and even i had the same question but by looking at the question and pseudo-code he/she just want to add the condition before replacing. I can't sit and assume things!!

Comment: @Pradeep no that wasn't criticism, your answer is solid. I just noticed this question and wanted to make sure we're interpreting this the way OP wanted it to. :)